# Push value in array of mongodb document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have one mongodb collection which have documents like these
[image]

now I want to push a value to rooms array of a document where email is abc@123.com ....
I have made this controller in node js.

```
module.exports.createroom = async (req,res) => {
    const {roomid,email} = req.body;
    UserModel.updateOne(
        { email: email },
        {
          $push: { rooms: roomid}
        }
     )
     res.send('done')
    
}
```

user schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    rooms:{
        type:Array
 }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

correct syntax for updating the record.

Comment: What is the question and the error?

Comment: the above code is giving status code of 200 and value is not getting pushed in the array..the question is to help in finding the mistake

Comment: Can you add User schema to the question? Also you need to add `await` in front of `UserModel.updateOne`

Comment: Please don't accept or upvote answers without any explanations, and copying the info from comments.

Comment: @SuleymanSah that answer worked excately fine for my question i was usig wrong function and that all i wanted to ask that wethere my method is correct or not. i treid your suggestion also for updateOne but it havent worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in your controller..

```
module.exports.createroom = async (req,res) => {
    const {roomid,email} = req.body;
    const user = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email : email },
        { $push: { rooms: roomid }  },
      )
    res.send("done")
}
```